# distribute graph data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, titan, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am loading some graph data sing titan API and configured cassandra as the storage backend. My graph data has around 1 million vertices. I want this data to be distributed across N cassandra nodes.

So for this, I configured 3 nodes in same system with IPs for each node as `127.0.0.1` , `127.0.0.2` and `127.0.0.3`. The output of nodetool status shows all 3 IPs and load shared equally.

I tried loading a graph but the whole data is replicated in all 3 nodes (1M vertices in node1, 1M vertices in node2 and 1M vertices in node3). I want the data to be distributed across all 3 nodes, like 1M/3 in node1, 1M/3 in node2 and 1M/3 in node3.

output of `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE TITAN`:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE titan WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} AND durable_writes = true;
```

output of nodetool status:

```
Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving -- Address Load Tokens Owns Host ID Rack 
UN 127.0.0.1 7.79 MB 1 ? f5a689f0-f4c1-4f68-ab81-58066e986cd4 rack1 
UN 127.0.0.2 229.79 KB 1 ? b6940e7e-b6eb-4d1f-959e-b5bd0f5cea15 rack1 
UN 127.0.0.3 7.11 MB 1 ? a3244b16-a73c-4801-868f-05de09615ed9 rack1
```

Can someone please share me the details on correct configurations to share the load. Please correct me in case anything is wrong.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Can you also detail in your question the cqlsh output of the keyspace showing the replication factor? Also the output of `nodetool status` for a bit of extra detail

Comment: output of DESCRIBE KEYSPACE TITAN --> CREATE KEYSPACE titan WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} AND durable_writes = true;
-----------------------------------------------------------
output of nodetool status --> Status=Up/Down |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving -- Address Load Tokens Owns Host ID Rack UN 127.0.0.1 7.79 MB 1 ? f5a689f0-f4c1-4f68-ab81-58066e986cd4 rack1 UN 127.0.0.2 229.79 KB 1 ? b6940e7e-b6eb-4d1f-959e-b5bd0f5cea15 rack1 UN 127.0.0.3 7.11 MB 1 ? a3244b16-a73c-4801-868f-05de09615ed9 rack1